# VisualSudio searching for .css class in .scss

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

I'm wondering if there is a possibility/plugin to quickly find some class for example

If my scss look like

```
#test { 
  .test { 
    p { }
  }
}
```

i would to go to `p { }` defintion after searching for text "#test .text p"

Comment: I do not understand your question. What are you actually looking for? CSS selectors are **selectors**. Which means that if you want to select this particular embeded `p`, you would need to write the full selector `#test .test p`.

Comment: I just want to go quickly to the definition that i have to edit.  I see in chrome dev tool definition "#test .test p"   its hard to quickly find this definition in my scss file.